# Validation against the non generic attribute of a generic type

Tags: c#, .net, validation, .net-core

I want to validate a class, that has a property of a generic type:

```
class Foo
{
   [ValidHistoryDate]
   public MyType<string> bar;
   [ValidHistoryDate]
   public MyType<int> baz;
   [ValidHistoryDate]
   public MyType<float> bat;
}
class MyType<T>
{
   public string date;
   public T property;
}
```

The generic type also contains a date, attribute (string), that should be validated against a valid date, so I wrote this function to do this:

```
public class ValidHistoryDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return true;
        var v = (List<MyType<object>>)value;
        bool valid = true;
        foreach (var f in v)
        {
            if (!Regex.Match(f.Date, @"^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}$").Success)
                valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

The validation does not care about the property "property", but it should care about the string.
Unfortunately the cast fails:

```
        var v = (List<MyType<object>>)value;
```

I mean: Of course it does, because "object" is not the real type. I want to use the validation attribute for all types and in the validation I actually do not even care about "property".

Any way to solve this in a nice way? I do not want to add a ValidHistoryDateAttribute for every possible type.

Comment: Why are you keeping dates as strings? If you would keep then as DateTime you wouldn't need this validation at all...

Comment: Should your type Foo actually have `List<MyType<string>>` properties on them? Otherwise I'm confused about why your validation attribute is talking about lists (and given this seems to be the heart of the problem this seems quite important to understand).

Comment: Without being sure what your exact code is I can tentatively suggest considering a base class that has your string date on it and is then inherited by your generic classes. This means you wouldn't need to know the generic type of your type since you can get everything you need from the non-generic subclass. If you can change the `List<GenericHistory<T>>` to `IEnumerable<GenericHistory<T>>` as well that might help with variance issues.

Comment: Also, your regular expression will allow strings such as `55.77.9999`. Instead of a regular expression, use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to do this I would add a non-generic base type into your code:

```
public class ValidatableObject
{
    public string date;
}
```

And then my class would be:

```
class MyType<T> : ValidatableObject
{
   public T property;
}
```

Your validation code would then refer to the base class which makes things a lot simpler.

It looks like you are actually trying to cast something of type `List<GenerericHistory<T>>` which will run into Variance problems. If you are assuming you are using my base class the incoming item cannot easily be converted to `List<ValidatableObject>` - to see why consider that the actual list should only allow adding of `GenerericHistory<T>` (where T is a specific type) objects whereas a `List<ValidatableObject>` would allow adding of `GenerericHistory<T>` objects of *any* type. Thus the cast is not allowed.

If you were to change the list to an `IEnumerable<GenerericHistory<T>>` then you would be able to cast to `IEnumerable<ValidatableObject>`. The reason is that this time we have a readOnly object so all we are doing is getting out objects of type `ValidatableObject` and since know that the actual class will only ever return `GenerericHistory<T>` (for specific T) we also know it always returns of type ValidatableObject and thus this time the cast is allowed.

The last bit is based partly on speculation since your code seems to be inconsistent with regards to the use of `List<T>` in your code. I assume the validator is correct that a property on your validatable object is a list but obviously I have no idea if that List can be changed, etc.

Comment: I just simplified my example and changed GenericHistory with "MyType". You answered my question perfectly. Awesome. I really like this idea and it should work.